# Why can certain Class objects not be passed as return values in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, reflection

Consider the following code which tries to work with the non-NSObject class object `__NSMessageBuilder`:

```
- (Class)getTestClass {
    Class class = objc_getClass("__NSMessageBuilder");
    return class;
}

- (void)testNonNSObjectClass {

    // case 1
    Class class1 = objc_getClass("__NSMessageBuilder");
    const char *name1 = class_getName(class1);

    // case 2
    Class class2 = [self getTestClass];
    const char *name2 = class_getName(class2);

}
```

The first case works as expected and name1 contains the correct name of the class. However, the execution crashes on `[self getTestClass]` in case 2 with the following seemingly unrelated log output:

```
NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fff76f18dc0 of class '__NSMessageBuilder' does not 
implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

This does not make any sense to me. What is going on here, and how can I fix it? The problem is not limited to `__NSMessageBuilder`, this also happens with other special classes like `__ARCLite__` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably because you are using ARC. The compiler is adding retain/release messages to your code, and because your root class does not inherit from NSObject, the retain and release methods have not been implemented you get the error "class '__NSMessageBuilder' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort".

I just made a test with the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// RootClass.h
NS_ROOT_CLASS
@interface RootClass
@end

// RootClass.m
#import "RootClass.h"
@implementation RootClass
@end

// AppDelegate.m
#import "RootClass.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (retain) IBOutlet NSWindow *window; // retain is important here because you will not use ARC in one of the tests
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    [self testNonNSObjectClass];
}

- (Class)getTestClass {
    Class class = objc_getClass("RootClass");
    return class;
}

- (void)testNonNSObjectClass {

    // case 1
    Class class1 = objc_getClass("RootClass");
    const char *name1 = class_getName(class1);

    // case 2
    Class class2 = [self getTestClass];
    const char *name2 = class_getName(class2);

}
```

If I run it with ARC it bombs like you found, but if you run this code without ARC (go to build phases and add the compiler flag -fno-objc-arc to AppDelegate.m) and you will not bomb.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced that memory management is the cause. The mentioned system classes are system classes with an unlimited lifetime, why would they get deallocated? `objc_getClass` just returns a reference to an existing class object. Also, it's not the subsequent `class_getName` which crashes, but the invocation of `getTestClass` itself. And one more remark: I'm not creating non-NSObject classes myself, these are existing classes I want to reflect ;)

Comment: But you might be on the right track: maybe the compiler inserts `retain` and `release` calls which are not understood by these objects. Then the question remains: How can I handle this case?

Comment: I would recommend that if you really want to go through that path then you must learn how to work with the runtime. That will be essential because NSObject hides much of the runtime's complexity. Therefore go here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-retain and start using objc_retain and objc_release or objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue. See which ones work for you.

Comment: Moreover disable ARC in these files and do manual memory management. Most probably that'll solve your problem.

Comment: OK, we were both right ;) I edited my answer to reflect what was really happening. Disable ARC like I said above and you'll be fine.

Comment: I will accept your answer because it brought me on the right track. However, I certainly won't disable ARC just for that; looks like treating classes as `void *` fixes the issue and is doable.